# Textural reference(s) for Bhadda Kapilani, a practitioner who for many lifetimes made the aspiration to be reborn as a woman?

Tags: reference-request, gender, bhikkhuni, aspiration

I just read '. . . Bhadda Kapilani, a practitioner who for many lifetimes made the aspiration to be reborn as a woman.' What are the textural references for this?

Answer (score 1):

An overview regarding [Bhadda Kapilani Theri](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/b/bhadda_kapilani_thi.htm) can be found in Palikanon. Nothing here talks about her wanting to be reborn a woman. She seems to have always been reborn a woman according to this page.

Here are some other references:

There is one entry in [Thig 4.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thig/thig.04.01.hekh.html).

There's another very long entry on Bhadda Kapilani on [Thi Ap 27](https://suttacentral.net/thi-ap27/en/walters?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true).

> “The foremost of my nun disciples who recollect past lives is Bhaddā daughter of Kapila."
> [AN 1.5.10](https://suttacentral.net/an1.235-247/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin)

The long story from the AN commentary can be found here: [AA 1.5.10](https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/English-Texts/Foremost-Elder-Nuns/10-Bhadda-Kapilani.htm).

The same story can be found in Ven. Sujato's blog entry: [Kassapa and Bhadda Kapilani](https://sujato.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/kassapa-and-bhadda-kapilani/).

There is a story of Bhadda Kapilani in [Chapter 2: Bhadda Kapilani](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel345.html#ch2) of Hellmuth Hecker's essay entitled [Maha Kassapa: Father of the Sangha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel345.html).

There are many more references on Bhadda Kapilani, many of them in the Vinaya. You can search for "[Bhadda Kapilani](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=bhadda%20kapilani)" on Sutta Central to find these.